# GIT Dev/Testing/Production Environment Best Practices

Tags: git, version-control

I want to implement GIT on my apps, I have read some best practices about branching in projects (like this: http://nvie.com/posts/a-successful-git-branching-model/) and I am going to implement them.

But I have a Question about how to manage each environment by remotes origins, not just in branches, For Example:

```
git remote add staging Gitserver:/git/stage_repos/repo.git
git remote add production Gitserver:/git/production_repos/repo.git
git remote add dev Gitserver:/git/dev_repos/repo.git

git push staging staging-branch
git push production master
git push dev dev-branch
```

My Question is, if I have to create 3 BARE repositories on GitRemoteServer for each environments to push them, and after enter to the AppServer(in prod,dev or stage) and do the PULL?

Or

If there is a way to create a Remote Init Repository(Not Bare) in the real Stage and Production Environment when I can push my commits and immediately view the changes on them, without to enter the server and apply PULL?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a [post commit hook](http://git-scm.com/book/ch7-3.html) on the server and have it automagically copy all the data to your live directory.

You also might consider using some other tool, like Jenkins for continuous integration, to actually manage the deployment.

Comment: Hi Wayne, sorry by answer late, but I think this is not the resolution that I want, but it will be useful to me to implement a hook to send emails in every commit.

Now about my Question I am going to keep a main remote repository and create branches/tags to do the fetch and after the checkout for the branch/tag, thats the best solution that I found. Thanks you for your help :D

Comment: If you found a different solution, you should post it as an answer and accept that (or, if my answer is sufficient enough you could accept it)